# List to dict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with this format 
`l = ['Rick', 25, 'Student', 'rick@mail.com']`
and I need a dict with this format

```
{'Name': 'Rick', 'Age': 25, 'E-mail': 'rick@mail.com', 'Position': 'Student'}
```

In my head the solution is iterate over the list and put each value inside the key dict. Are there other (Simplified) solution?

Comment: In my head, I'll just zip the list with a list of keys (keys first) and then call `dict` on the zipped lists.

Comment: What is the purpose of the ‘Student’ entry in the list?

Comment: Where did "Student" go?

Comment: I just forget to mention student in my list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
keys = ['name', 'age', 'job', 'email']
values = ['Rick', 25, 'Student', 'rick@mail.com']

key_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))
print(key_dict)

# {'name': 'Rick', 'age': 25, 'job': 'Student', 'email': 'rick@mail.com'}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `zip()` to join the keys and the values in `l` together, and then convert to a dictionary with `dict` as seen here:

```
>>> dict(zip(('Name', 'Age', 'Role', 'E-mail'), l))
{'Name': 'Rick', 'E-mail': 'rick@mail.com', 'Role': 'Student', 'Age': 25}
```

Or, if you wanted to omit the `'Student'` element all together, you could just slice at the third index:

```
>>> dict(zip(('Name', 'Age', 'E-mail'), l[:2] + l[3:]))
{'Name': 'Rick', 'E-mail': 'rick@mail.com', 'Age': 25}
```

Or use a `generator`:

```
>>> dict(zip(('Name', 'Age', 'E-mail'), (a for a in l if a is not 'Student')))
{'Name': 'Rick', 'E-mail': 'rick@mail.com', 'Age': 25}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use zip(). It will merge to lists into an immutable dict.

```
keys = ['name', 'age', 'position', 'email']
values = ['Rick', 25, 'Student', 'rick@mail.com']
zippeddict = dict(zip(keys, values))
```